HStack centering of elements
In my VStack I have this:
VStack {
    Text("\(match.initiator!) VS \(match.performer!)")
        .border(Color.green, width: 1)
        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .bold))
        .foregroundColor(Color.black )
                
        HStack {
            Text(match.outcome! ? "WIN : LOSE" : "LOSE : WIN")
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
        }
}

Problem is that the colon between "WIN" and "LOSE" is being moved around, depending on the outcome. I want it to always be in the center, regardless of the position of WIN and LOSE, regarding of the length of "WIN" and "LOSE" text parts. How can I center the whole wording around ":" character?

If the text elements are shown individually, then maxWidth: .infinity can be set on the first and the last elements, which will cause them to share the space available. The ":" will then be sandwiched exactly in the middle.
HStack {
    Text(match.outcome! ? "WIN" : "LOSE")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    Text(":")
    Text(match.outcome! ? "LOSE" : "WIN")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}
.font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))

Alternatively, if you want the HStack to have the minimum width necessary, you can use a hidden placeholder to establish the footprint for the individual words. Then show the words themselves as an overlay over the footprint:
private var winLoseFootprint: some View {
    ZStack {
        Text("WIN")
        Text("LOSE")
    }
    .hidden()
}

HStack {
    winLoseFootprint
        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text(match.outcome! ? "WIN" : "LOSE")
        }
    Text(":")
    winLoseFootprint
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(match.outcome! ? "LOSE" : "WIN")
        }
}
.font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))

